# Is htmlspecialchars necessary here?

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

In this situation is it overkill to use htmlspecialchars? I have checked to see if the input is only made up of digits, but is there any way anything other than a number can sneak through into the code?

```
if (ctype_digit($input)){
    $sanitized=htmlspecialchars($input);
}
```

Comment: it's safe enough. but note that it's basically looking for anything that ISN'T 0-9, so `10` will pass, but `1.3` and `1e30` would both fail. It's looking purely for digits, and won't pass many things that are valid numbers, but contain non-digits.

Comment: No, you shouldn't use it here

Comment: Cheers, I only need it purely for digits so it sounds like it should be okay.

Comment: You sanitise whenever your data is changing context, ***i.e.*** if you pass a string to a regex engine, to mysql or *HTML* output *(browser being the different runtime context)* etc. and you use an appropriate escape function specific to each case.  If you aren't printing the value again sometime soon after this code block then the chances are you may only introduce odd behaviour into any logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to use here, since it will verify that every character in that string is an integer between 0 and 9, so there isn't a way for non-digits to get in.

However, you're not necessarily checking if something is a number, for that, you should use `is_numeric($num)`, and while in this case you don't have to use `htmlspecialchars()`, if you're going for consistency, you should use that on all input